# ContentFlow javascript - reloading images after filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering, coverflow

I am using the following "Coverflow" javascript, [ContentFlow](http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/)

and have a filter function to search the Contentflow for image titles and filter them. I need the Contentflow to reload with the filtered images after the search function. I have the following code which works for filtering and reloading the "flow" but it reloads all the images, not the filtered images. Obviously, I don't have the right code to do this and I need a bit of help to get the filtered images loaded.

```
$("#filter").keyup(function(){
global.canChangeImage = true;
    // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
    var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0; 
    // Loop through the comment list
    $("a.item").each(function(){
        // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
            $(this).fadeOut();
        // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
        } else {
            $(this).show();
 var contentFlow = new ContentFlow('contentFlow');
       contentFlow._init();    
           count++;
        }
    });

    // Update the count
    var numberItems = count;
    $("#filter-count").text(count+" Images Found");

  });
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You may use an array to store all your images' info and then use [ContentFlow](http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/docu.php)'s `addItem()` and `rmItem()` functions depending on the filter condition and the array.

With this approach you could reload the flow dynamically from the array items.